# Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor while converting pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to convert a pandas dataframe to a tf dataset, but i constantly rrun into this problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/arch_poppin/dev/AI/reviews/rev.py", line 36, in <module>
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, label.values))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 689, in from_tensor_slices
    return TensorSliceDataset(tensors)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/ops/dataset_ops.py", line 3066, in __init__
    element = structure.normalize_element(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/data/util/structure.py", line 129, in normalize_element
    ops.convert_to_tensor(t, name="component_%d" % i, dtype=dtype))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/profiler/trace.py", line 163, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1535, in convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_conversion_registry.py", line 52, in _default_conversion_function
    return constant_op.constant(value, dtype, name=name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 264, in constant
    return _constant_impl(value, dtype, shape, name, verify_shape=False,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 276, in _constant_impl
    return _constant_eager_impl(ctx, value, dtype, shape, verify_shape)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 301, in _constant_eager_impl
    t = convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 98, in convert_to_eager_tensor
    return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int).
```

this is my code looks like:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
import io
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# In[0] open file
df = pd.read_csv(r'PATH')
df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)


# In[1] make comma separated integers into list

objectColumnList = list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns)

for column in objectColumnList:
    colArr = []
    for row in df[column]:
        arr = np.asarray(row.split(',')).astype(np.float32)
        colArr.append(arr)
    df[column] = colArr

# In[2] mnake datatset

label = df.pop('MYLABELS')

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((df.values, label.values))
```

Now the link to the csv file I'm using, if you want reproduce the error:
https://mega.nz/file/uOwiwK5K#FVG7K0glMh2mGa53UDWQiG6iKgNFn5972Kdjb-gmAV4 I had to remove the column names for privacy reasons

Comment: Tell us about `df.values` and `label.values`.  In particular what's the `dtype`?

Comment: Ints for the majority of the values, those that are single integers; object for the arrays

Comment: If you have a mix of ints and arrays, then the `df.values.dtype`  is object.  Tensorflow can't make a tensor from that kind of mix.  It requires all numbers, with a numeric dtype.